# SpringBoot画面更新させたい

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

現在表示している画面でボタンを押して画面の再描画を行いたいです。

location.reload();

上記で更新できるようなのですが、
値を渡したく、ajaxを利用してPUTすればいいのでは…と思い
以下のような処理をjavascriptで実施するようにしました。
javascriptにパラメータのidとnoを渡しています。

以下のように実装しており、コントローラー側に期待した値がわたってくること、
javascript側のdoneにresponseDataがわたってくることまでは確認できているのですが
doneでどのようにして現在表示しているupdate.htmlを
更新させるのかがわかりません…。
アドバイスいただけると助かります。

＃このようなやり方ではまずいのかもしれません

■javascript

```
$.ajax({
    type : "put",
    url : "update",
    data: {
        id : id,
        no : no
       },
    dataType : "html"
}).done(function(responseData, status, jqXHR) {
★ここでどうやれば結果を画面に更新できるのかがよくわかりません…。
}).fail(function(responseError, status, errorThrown) {
});
```

■コントローラー

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView reload(@RequestParam("id") int id,
        @RequestParam("no") String no) {

    // 渡されたid、noパラメータをもとにDBからupdateInfoを取得しています。

    mav.setViewName("update");
    mav.addObject("updateInfo", updateInfo);

    return mav;
}
```

Comment: どこにどのようなデータを表示したいのかによると思います。例えば、id="hoge" 以下に挿入したい場合には、$('#hoge').append(responseData)等でできます。

Comment: 説明不足で申し訳ありません。すでにupdateInfoを表示している状態で、別の値（idとno）で検索した結果で得られるupdateInfoを更新したいと考えています。appendの場合挿入になると考えるのですが、行いことは入れ替えたい…という感じです。

Comment: 単純に値を渡してリロードしたいということでしょうか？同一の画面遷移であれば、ボタンを押したときにGETないしPOSTでSpring側にパラメータを渡し、HTMLを再描画すればいいように思えます。

Comment: webarata3 さま、コメントありがとうございます！$('#xxx').html(responseData);で表示可能でした。指定したIDがおかしかったのが原因でした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

画面の一部を書き換えるには、例えば、[$.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)が使えると思います。

次の様なHTMLがある場合、

```
<div id="hoge">ほげ</div>
```

次のコードで 「ほげ」 を 「ふが」 に変えられます。

```
$('#hoge').text('ふが');
```

このコードの結果は次のようになります。

```
<div id="hoge">ふが</div>
```

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。$('#hoge').html(responseData);のような形で変更可能でした！